# @nestjs/bull -- Add one consumer as provider to more than one module

Tags: nestjs

Added as a provider the service and the consumer in more than one module, and I get this error: throw new Error('Cannot define the same handler twice ' + name);
Already tried to create a separate module with them and import in the modules that need this classes but the jobs are not processed by the consumer in prod, only in local.

Steps to reproduce:

- create a consumer and a producer service
- add the consumer and the producer service as providers to more than one module
- error

Expected behavior:
Jobs must be processed by the consumer

@nestjs/bull - ^0.5.5
bull - ^4.8.2
@nestjs/core - ^8.4.5
node.js - 18.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Instead of injecting consumer into two different services (which is not allowed as you mentioned), inject consumer into a separate service then inject those couple of services into it. Then route each process to their correct service's method.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Created a separate service and module, and then imported the consumer and the services as providers in the new module. Now I dont have the error but the consumer continues to not process the jobs. Also imported the new module in the app module and in the modules that uses the new service.

Comment: First be sure that BullModule is registered at App module level: `BullModule.forRootAsync...` for example. Then be sure both customer and producer modules register the queue by  `BullModule.registerQueue({name: 'YOU_QUEUE_NAME_HERE' })`

Comment: Also run `monitor` form redis-cli to be sure the job is produced.

Comment: yap, I have BullModule.forRoot({... in app module and a module with the services and the consumer as providers and the registerQueue, but consumer only process jobs in local but not in prod

Comment: Could you provide the code for your solution @RitaMoreira ?

Comment: Hey! I don't have a solution for this problem! I don't know if it takes some extra implementation or adding some key to work in prod! I just managed to get it to work locally!